# ContextMenuStrip location is not good because of PointToScreen

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have a `Button` in a `SplitContainer`, on panel2. 
I have created dynamically a `ContextMenuStrip` which I have attached to this Button. I want to positioning the context menu under the button like in this image

[image]

But what I got is not like that.

This is what I tried:

```
private void SelectContentGroup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ContextMenuStrip x = selectContentGroup.ContextMenuStrip;
    if (x is null) return;
        // this will show contextmenu near the mouse arrow
        //x.Show(Control.MousePosition);

        // I have tried to get MousePosition and to compare to my button location and Y is a lot of difference, about 200 pixels
        //Console.WriteLine("MousePosition: {0}, ButtonLocation: {1}", Control.MousePosition, PointToScreen(selectContentGroup.Location));
        x.Show(PointToScreen(selectContentGroup.Location));

        // I tried with e.Location also, but none of those points will give the button Left-Bottom position for contextmenu
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method that includes the control, and adjust by the height of that control to have the menu show below it:

```
x.Show(SelectContentGroup, new Point(0, SelectContentGroup.Height));
```

I'm assuming SelectContentGroup is the name of the button.